# Error when gem installing Jekyll in cmd

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I have tried to install Jekyll on windows(x64) with the aid of the guide of @juthilo. And when installing jekyll as a gem (through the cmd command "gem install jekyll") an error prompts:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I would be thankful if you could tell me how to fix that. The fact is, I don't even understand the ERROR itself.